# General questions about JHipster

Tags: jhipster

Sorry if this is not a place to ask these questions. But I just want to know if...

1. Can JHipster go large scale applications?
2. Is it possible to minimize the generation of codes especially with the UI part?
3. Can I extend some RestController class that has been generated to. (Like a custom model class where in I get base64 string to write in a file)

Sorry again for asking, its just that I'm building a startup business and I want to know if these are all possible. I can't help but to get over excited on JHipster and I'm literally crossing my fingers now!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Three questions in one, in fact!

1. It depends of what you call "large scale". We have users with several hundreds of tables, so that's what I would qualify as "large". Other people use a "micro service" approach, with several JHipster apps working together, and that's what I'd recommend. Our Gatling tests (as well as feedback from users) also show we are able to sustain a large amount of HTTP requests, compared to "competing" stacks such as JBoss or Play! (but both of them don't have default settings oriented towards production, like our "prod" profile - for example they don't have a 2nd level cache enabled by default - so that's normal we are much more performant out-of-the-box)
2. If you don't like the UI part you can remove it, but in that case I would recommend not using JHipster -> this is the whole idea, otherwise just use a bona fide Spring Boot, or DropWizard
3. It's just a generator, so yes you can extend or modify anything that was generated

Comment: Thanks Julien! I like how you guys generate even the angularJS part, but I just don't prefer using bootstrap that much. That's the only problem I have in JHipster. But this is amazing! I guess I have nothing to say but to try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, i have used it for one educational board who have 20housand+ js file, and also used it for 3 ministry